# Custom LeftBarButtonItem not responding to touches?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have the following custom sized LeftBarButtonItem and sometimes its not responding to my touches like 60% of the time it responds

```
        UIImage yourBackImage = UIImage.FromBundle("back-button");
        var newSize = new CGSize(20, 20);
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0f);
        yourBackImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));
        UIImage resizeImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        UIButton backButton = new UIButton(UIButtonType.System);
        backButton.SetImage(resizeImage.ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), UIControlState.Normal);
        backButton.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 44, 44);
        backButton.TouchUpInside += delegate
        {
            DetailController dc = new DetailController();
            NavigationController.PushViewController(dc, false);
        };
        backButton.ImageEdgeInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -13.0f, bottom: 0, right: 13.0f);

        backButton.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(44.0f).Active = true;
        backButton.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(44.0f).Active = true;
        NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(backButton);
```

Comment: `backButton.TouchUpInside += delegate` looks a little odd, perhaps your delegate is being clobbered?

Comment: @brandonscript I don't think that is a problem because I have that all over the code base and it works fine, only when it is BarButtonItem is when I have problems.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is the touch area, but it doesn’t look small (44x44?)